# Unable to copy files from NSBundle to Document Directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to copy my database from the NSBundle to the Document Directory.

This is the code to copy a file:

```
- (NSString *) getDBPath 
{
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  return [documentsDir stringByAppendingString:@"Mydata.sqlite"];
}

- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded 
{
  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  NSError *error;
  NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
  BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

  if(!success) {

    NSString *defaultPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Mydata.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

    if (!success)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
  }
}
```

But why is it that when i run this application on my iPad, it crashes?

Comment: I have found out why it crashes!
The problem lies here: return [documentsDir stringByAppendingString:@"Mydata.sqlite"];

Should use stringByAppendingPathComponent instead.

Answer (score 0):

check this line

```
NSString *defaultPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Photo.png"];
```

I think This is wrong path

Comment: Oh my bad. I made a mistake while posting the question. Yes i've changed it to "Mydata.sqlite" but it still crashes.

Comment: Have u created the file with sqlite extension.Sometimes u may miss

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Core Data my advice is to manage the DB "move" at startup.
Just use the Core Data Stack management (you will get it for free from a built-in teplate).

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
    }

    NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyData.sqlite"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyData" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (defaultStorePath) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:NULL];
        }
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}

- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

I always use that code when I've to manage data.